# I need HTML special characters in variable

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a PHP variable and I need to use rich text formatting (like bold) but it is not possible with the code I have.

How could I do this?

For example:

My text:

`<td>{{ $item->item_category->name ?? "Eliminaste esta Categoría" }}</td>`

But I need:

`<td>{{ $item->item_category->name ?? "<b>Eliminaste esta Categoría</b>" }}</td>`

I tried the latest code but it doesn't work.

Comment: `<td><b>{{ $item->item_category->name ?? "Eliminaste esta Categoría" }}</b></td>` ?

Comment: Hello, I only need that if in case the value is null, it only becomes bold. You eliminated this Category and not the other value.
That's why I only put the <b> in the value "Eliminaste esta Categoría"

Comment: _" it doesn't work."_ - so please explain what is happening, and how that differs from what you expect.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend following Watercayman's answer, but if you really want to do it your current way, you can use `{!! $item->item_category->name ?? "<b>Eliminaste esta Categoría</b>" !!}` as detailed in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data).

Comment: @Kirk Beard put it as an answer please to put it as an outstanding answer friend you are great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd recommend following [Watercayman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67963986/248567), but if you really want to do it your current way, you can use:

```
{!! $item->item_category->name ?? "<b>Eliminaste esta Categoría</b>" !!}
```

as detailed in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data).

To explain the difference between the two:

`{{ $var }}` runs `echo htmlspecialchars($var);` which does several things, including converting `<b>` to `&lt;b&gt;`.

Running the alternative `{!! $var !!}` simply does `echo $var`.

The reason you might (should) use the first option is to sanitise user submitted data to prevent potential security risks. In your case, since it's a hard coded string that you've written, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You're the best. I've been stuck with this for a long time. Thanks!!

Comment: @EduardoRafael No worries, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

Keep the potentially dangerous data value escaped, then and un-escape the text you are adding (known text) as simple, plain html:

```
@if(isset($item->item_category->name))
    <td>{{ $item->item_category->name }}</td>
@else
    <td><b>Eliminaste esta Categoría</b></td>
@endif
```